# Simple JUnit test not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, junit

Hi I am trying to run a basic JUnit test in Android Studio. When I click run it is terminated every time before getting results. I never get pass or fail and the system does not try any other test cases.

Here are the pictures. I would like to know why it isn't working so I can keep practicing.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try a couple of things

Decorate your test class with @SmallTest

```
// @RunWith is required only if you use a mix of JUnit3 and JUnit4.
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@SmallTest
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
}
```

Try to run your test from the command line:

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```